# php - website security using global variable

Tags: php, security, forum, phpbb

i was recently browsing some php source code, particularly ones of forum software like phpbb and esotalk

I noticed one thing, most of them used a global variable at the start of their page as some sort of security like so:

```
if (!defined("IN_ESOTALK")) exit; //For esotalk
if (!defined("IN_PHPBB")) exit; //FOR phpbb
```

What sort of security is this? I don't understand. 
Could you explain to me what this prevents and how?

thanks,
Vidhu

Comment: This to prevent access the script from outside the application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it works by making sure the php script doesn't run unless the framework has started up. This way the user can't execute a script without going through the proper page.

Here's an example. We have 2 files:

index.php

```
<?php
     define("_MY_FRAMEWORK", 1);
     echo 'started';
     require('script.php');
?>
```

and script.php

```
<?php
    if (!defined("_MY_FRAMEWORK")) exit;
    echo "my script";
?>
```

If you run script.php directly, nothing will happen because `_MY_FRAMEWORK` has not been defined. it will exit.

However, if you run index.php, which includes script.php, the script will continue because you did define `_MY_FRAMEWORK` first. You will get the full output: `started` followed by `my script`.

@Gumbo makes a good point: If you haven't seen define before, it defines a constant that cannot be changed. The [user contributions to the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) can be helpful to understand how it works.

Comment: You should mention that these are constants and not variables.

Answer (score 1):

This also prevents variable manipulation by using register_globals.

If register_globals is enabled in php.ini, users are able to modify variables in the script by changing the variable in the URL, but this would not allow them to modify the value of constant variables that were defined using the define function

Answer (score 1):

These are global constants. With these they make sure their software is running how it's intended.